# Missing Search and Pagination Features in Angular DataTable When Using Custom Spinner with REST API"

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-datatables

I'm using a spinner in my Angular data table to indicate that data is loading. Despite having a large dataset, the default features for "Searching," "Pagination," and column sorting do not appear after the data has been loaded into the table. below is my code

```
export class MyLayoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit 
{
title: string | undefined;

path: string | undefined;

data: any[] = [];

xmlData: String[] = [];

dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
selectedRowData: string | undefined;
screenHeight: any;
scrollFraction: any;
scrollYValue: any;
errorAlert: boolean = false;
isLoading: boolean = true;

constructor(private restApi: MyApiService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 100,
  lengthMenu: [100, 200, 300],
  searching: true,
  autoWidth: true,
};
this.fetchData();
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
}

fetchData() {
this.restApi.getMyReq()
  .pipe(finalize(() => this.isLoading = false))
  .subscribe(
    (response: any) => {
      this.data = response;
      this.initializeDataTable();
    },
    error => {
      console.error('Error fetching data', error);
    }
  );
  }

  initializeDataTable() {
    this.dtTrigger.next(0);
  }
  }
```

When I include a setTimeout() in the initializeDataTable() method, the spinner comes for some time and gets disabled, and after a 2-second delay table appears correctly with all the default features.
Below is the relevant code snippet.

```
  initializeDataTable() {
     setTimeout(() => {
        this.dtTrigger.next(0);
       }, 2000); // Delay of 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
  }
```

Can anyone offer assistance? Adding a delay isn't an ideal solution, so I'm looking for alternative approaches to address this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.dtOptions = {
  deferRender: true,
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 100,
  lengthMenu: [100, 200, 300],
  searching: true,
  autoWidth: true,
  initComplete: () => {
    this.spinnerService.hide() ;// this piece of code fixing my problem. 
  }
};
```